# Unable to load OpenStreetMap in EXE freeze application

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, openstreetmap

After creating the EXE application via cx_Freze, everything works normally. Vector layers are displayed and all map viewer functions work, but OSM maps cannot be loaded. But I also run it through a Python script, so OSM will be displayed. Where could be the problem?

```
def nacitaj_tiles_OSM(self):
    urlWithParams = (
        "type=xyz&"
        "url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&"
        "zmax=19&"
        "zmin=0&"
        "crs=EPSG3857"
    )
    options = QgsRasterLayer.LayerOptions()
    options.skipCrsValidation = False
    self.osmLayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "OpenStreetMap", "wms", options)

    if not self.osmLayer.isValid():
        print("Vrstva OSM sa nedala načítať !")
        self.statusText.setText("Vrstva Open Street Maps sa nedala načítať !")
    else:
        self.project.addMapLayer(self.osmLayer, True)
        txtProjekciaPlatna = "{}".format(self.osmLayer.crs().authid())
        self.ProjectionStatus.setText(txtProjekciaPlatna)
```

layer: self.osmLayer  id not valid !!!

QGIS 3.22 and Python 3.9